# ionic 2 alignment text automatically

Tags: alignment, ionic2, direction

In my app i have **multiple language** in some time `english` and `arabic`, so i want to **adjust** **automatically** the `alignment` of the text in two case `english` and `arabic`.

So How i can `alignment` **english** and **arabic** text **automatically** ex:

> if i have a english text in my app i want alignment to left and if
>   arabic text set alignment to right how i can do this automatically in
>   my application ?

**Note :** the text received from the server

**any suggestion about that ?**

**JSON:**

```
{
    "error": false,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "date": "2016-12-14T13:11:18+00:00",
    "message": "",
    "details": [],
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 117,
            "parent_id": 0,
            "subject": "هناك حقيقة مثبتة منذ زمن طويل وهي أن المحتوى المقروء لصفحة ما سيلهي القارئ عن التركيز على الشكل الخارجي للنص أو شكل توضع الفقرات في الصفحة التي يقرأها.",
            "message": "هناك حقيقة مثبتة منذ زمن طويل وهي أن المحتوى المقروء لصفحة ما سيلهي القارئ عن التركيز على الشكل الخارجي للنص أو شكل توضع الفقرات في الصفحة التي يقرأها.",
            "data": null,
            "type": "normal",
            "created_at": 1481629305,
            "updated_at": 1481629305,
            "typeColor": "#00A65A",
        },
        {
            "id": 117,
            "parent_id": 0,
            "subject": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
            "message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
            "data": null,
            "type": "normal",
            "created_at": 1481629305,
            "updated_at": 1481629305,
            "typeColor": "#00A65A",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: why not just create a global sass file that handles the language type globally ?

Comment: i have do that but the text received from the server i want to detect automatically if english or arabic and set the alignment.

Comment: why not let the service tell you if its english or arabic ? then from there you can use css to format it,  there's no language detection in ionic

Answer (score 0):

try to use ngclass to achive this

you css

```
.englisAlign{
   text-align: left;
}
.arabicAlign{
   text-align: right;
}
```

your html

```
 <div [ngClass]="languages ? 'englisAlign' : 'arabicAlign'">{{language }}</div>
```

in your ts file  make `languages` variable true or false based upon your need

Comment: thank you for your response but the text received from server so i want to detect it and set the alignment how i can do this ?